# Trouble with error “bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')”

Tags: python, ssl

I use python requests get() function to access data through API, after several times of getting data, the exception occurred: "bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')"

Following is the whole exception information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SysCallError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    455             try:
--> 456                 cnx.do_handshake()
    457             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1914         result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
-> 1915         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1916 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1639                         raise SysCallError(errno, errorcode.get(errno))
-> 1640                 raise SysCallError(-1, "Unexpected EOF")
   1641             else:

SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    593             if is_new_proxy_conn:
--> 594                 self._prepare_proxy(conn)
    595 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _prepare_proxy(self, conn)
    804         conn.set_tunnel(self._proxy_host, self.port, self.proxy_headers)
--> 805         conn.connect()
    806 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    343             server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 344             ssl_context=context)
    345 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    346         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 347             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    348 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    461             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
--> 462                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
    463             break

SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    398         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 399             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    400 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='min-api.cryptocompare.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/v4/all/exchanges?api_key=1bd6b034f5c37235fe86bd57125805ae1164b1f50aea15648073d27a3627b00e&e=Binance (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c02353795ce4> in <module>
     12         print(file_name + " is exist jump over")
     13     else:
---> 14         get_data(exchange, fsym, tsym, end)

<ipython-input-7-c40a18711b4e> in get_data(exchange, fsym, tsym, end)
     25 
     26 # Call function
---> 27     get_min_histo_data(apiKey, exchange, fsym, tsym, last_file, end)

<ipython-input-6-423ba0f217ce> in get_min_histo_data(apiKey, exchange, fsym, tsym, last_file, end)
     18 
     19     # Request data
---> 20     result_volumn = requests.get(url_vol, params=payload_volumn).json()
     21 
     22     # Get start and end timestamp

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

D:\Users\64249\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    512             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
    516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='min-api.cryptocompare.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/v4/all/exchanges?api_key=1bd6b034f5c37235fe86bd57125805ae1164b1f50aea15648073d27a3627b00e&e=Binance (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))
```

and here is my code(Relative part):

```
        url_data = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour"

        payload_data = {
        "api_key": apiKey,
        "e" : exchange,
        "fsym": fsym,
        "tsym": tsym,
        "limit": limit,
        "toTs": start_time
        }

        result = requests.get(url_data, params=payload_data,  verify=False).json()
```

The code was running well and could successfully gather data from that API around 80-100 times.
But after several times of getting data, that exception occurred: "bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')"

Comment: Maybe due to several frequent requests, they have blocked your IP

Comment: I would agree, check what the rate limit would be and see if it makes sense.  Speaking of which, for an entirely different site, I got 80 in before the errors appeared, so this appears typical.